# Why do I keep getting error when creating a React app?

Tags: reactjs, macos, intellij-idea, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to set up React to use with IntelliJ by following the [Intro to React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment) to create a tic-tac-toe game using option 2 on the website. I have created a Github repo and opened it in IntelliJ but when I try running

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

from the instructions on the React website I get this error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/Achoo/.npm/_cacache/tmp/a75502a6
npm ERR! dest /Users/Achoo/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/57/68/0820add9c5b0276e83c83872c39a38712d10cbe018a4165fcf7cb9fd1fe8880e552459135e3fa85f902263868e4e3d1e24a1f8a74a7c6b465b85c0921994
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/Achoo/.npm/_cacache/tmp/a75502a6' -> '/Users/Achoo/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/57/68/0820add9c5b0276e83c83872c39a38712d10cbe018a4165fcf7cb9fd1fe8880e552459135e3fa85f902263868e4e3d1e24a1f8a74a7c6b465b85c0921994'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Achoo/.npm/_logs/2023-02-27T08_19_33_932Z-debug-0.log
```

I have the most recent version of npm and node.js installed so I don't really know what's happening, any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: try cleaning the cache and try again. `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: still getting the same error